# How do I tell vim to default to a particular dialect of SQL for syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

From [vim's documentation](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/syntax.txt)

> Vim currently supports the Oracle and Informix dialects of
>   SQL.  Vim assumes "*.sql" files are Oracle SQL by default.

I am writing for Informix. How do I tell vim to use that dialect for syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

From the same [vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/ft_sql.html#sql-dialects):

> For the people that work with many different databases, it is nice to be able to flip between the various vendors rules (indent, syntax) on a per buffer basis, at any time.  The ftplugin/sql.vim file defines this function: `SQLSetType`

So run

```
:runtime ftplugin/sql.vim " If it's not already read
:SQLSetType sqlinformix
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the global default you need

```
let g:sql_type_default = 'sqlinformix'
```

`:SQLSetType` is used to change dialect for an open buffer.